# SQL Server Database Mail: HTML not rendering in Outlook and gmail

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, database-mail

I am using Database Mail in SQL Server and trying to send emails. I have created this simple html message for testing purposes:

```html
declare @body nvarchar(1000)
select @body = 

'<html><body>
<h3>Test Email</h3>
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <th>ID </th>
  <th>Name</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>John</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Marry</td> 
 </tr>
</table>
</body></html>'

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'myemail@gmail.com'
, @subject = 'Test', @body = @body, @reply_to = 'noreply@myserver.com', 
@from_address = 'noreply@myserver.com', @profile_name= 'My SMTP'
```

However, html is not rendered on both Outlook 2013 and Gmail. Its showing this:
[image]

Why is it not working?

Comment: I believe you need to set one more property to html instead of plain text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `body_format` property to HTML

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients = 'myemail@gmail.com'
, @subject = 'Test', @body = @body, @body_format='HTML', @reply_to = 'noreply@myserver.com', 
@from_address = 'noreply@myserver.com', @profile_name= 'My SMTP'
```

Run code snippetCopy snippet to answer